# C# List .ConvertAll Efficiency and overhead

Tags: c#, performance, list, convertall

I recently learned about List's .ConvertAll extension. I used it a couple times in code today at work to convert a large list of my objects to a list of some other object. It seems to work really well. However I'm unsure how efficient or fast this is compared to just iterating the list and converting the object. Does .ConvertAll use anything special to speed up the conversion process or is it just a short hand way of converting Lists without having to set up a loop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No better way to find out than to go directly to the source, literally :)

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#dbcc8a668882c0db

As you can see, there's no special magic going on. It just iterates over the list and creates a new item by the converter function that you specify.

To be honest, I was not aware of this method. The more idiomatic .NET way to do this kind of projection is through the use of the `Select` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` like so: `source.Select(input => new Something(input.Name))`. The advantage of this is threefold:

- It's more idomatic as I said, the `ConvertAll` is likely a remnant of the pre-C#3.0 days. It's not a very arcane method by any means and `ConvertAll` is a pretty clear description, but it might still be better to stick to what other people know, which is `Select`.
- It's available on *all* `IEnumerable<T>`, while `ConvertAll` only works on instances of `List<T>`. It doesn't matter if it's an array, a list or a dictionary, `Select` works with all of them.
- `Select` is lazy. It doesn't do anything until you iterate over it. This means that it returns an `IEnumerable<TOutput>` which you can then convert to a list by calling `ToList()` or not if you don't actually *need* a list. Or if you just want to convert and retrieve the first two items out of a list of a million items, you can simply do `source.Select(input => new Something(input.Name)).Take(2)`.

But if your question is purely about the performance of converting a whole list to another list, then `ConvertAll` is likely to be somewhat faster as it's less generic than a `Select` followed by a `ToList` (it knows that a list has a size and can directly access elements by index from the underlying array for instance).

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough reply! I curious as to which was the fastest so I put some stopwatches around each conversion method for .ConvertAll, .Select and the basic iteration and conversion. Each fell within milliseconds of each other. No notable difference. The basic iteration method was the fastest. .ConvertAll took second place and .Select was the slowest.

Comment: Great post! Note however that ToList() cannot be deferred so using a .ToList() at the end of you Select statement will force the whole thing to be executed directly.

For a list of all queries that cannot be deferred see this [classification page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution)

Answer (score 4):

Decompiled using ILSPy:

```
public List<TOutput> ConvertAll<TOutput>(Converter<T, TOutput> converter)
{
    if (converter == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.converter);
    }
    List<TOutput> list = new List<TOutput>(this._size);
    for (int i = 0; i < this._size; i++)
    {
        list._items[i] = converter(this._items[i]);
    }
    list._size = this._size;
    return list;
}
```

1. Create a new list.
2. Populate the new list by iterating over the current instance, executing the specified delegate.
3. Return the new list.

> Does .ConvertAll use anything special to speed up the conversion
>   process or is it just a short hand way of converting Lists without
>   having to set up a loop?

It doesn't do anything special with regards to conversion (what "special" thing could it do?) It is directly modifying the private `_items` and `_size` members, so it might be *trivially* faster under some circumstances.

As usual, if the solution makes you more productive, code easier to read, etc. use it until profiling reveals a compelling performance reason to *not* use it.

Comment: If you want the source, may as well use the Reference Source linked to by Julian: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,dbcc8a668882c0db

Answer (score 1):

It's the second way you described it - basically a short-hand way without setting up a loop.

Here's the guts of `ConvertAll()`:

```
List<TOutput> list = new List<TOutput>(this._size);
for (int index = 0; index < this._size; ++index)
  list._items[index] = converter(this._items[index]);
list._size = this._size;
return list;
```

Where `TOutput` is whatever type you're converting to, and `converter` is a delegate indicating the method that will do the conversion.

So it loops through the `List` you passed in, running each element through the method you specify, and then returns a new `List` of the specified type.

Answer (score 0):

For precise timing in your scenarios you need to measure yourself.

Do not expect any miracles - it have to be O(n) operation since each element need to be converted and added to destination list.

Consider using `Enumerable.Select` instead as it will do lazy evaluation that may allow avoiding second copy of large list, especially you you need to do any filtering of items along the way.